# Reordering divs based on screen size over rows

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying with Bootstrap to do the following on larger screens

```
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|  div1  |       div2      |  div3  |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

but when dropping down to smaller screens I need the following:

```
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|      div1       |      div3       |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                div2               |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

obviously the first part is easy:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">div1</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">div2</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">div3</div>
</div>
```

but adding the functionality for the second part is where I'm stuck.

I've tried the following, but it just ends up a mess, with the columns in the same order:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">div1</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-push-12">div2</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-pull-6">div3</div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: this may not be relevant to answer the question but why do you want it to be in that order? instead of normal ordering 1-2-3(12small).

Comment: @nCore Thanks for the reply. On my site, the content for `div2` will always be greater than that of `div1` and `div3` so it makes sense to keep them their relative sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution requires adding a clearfix to the small screen size:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        div1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-md-push-6">
        div3
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-pull-3">
        div2
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer actually works nicely with going to `xs` size. With [Pete's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27313966/1185053), there is a nasty effect if there is a background color on the divs (elements end up obscuring others).

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to re-order your divs you can use the following html and classes:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">div1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 pull-right">div3</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">div2</div>
</div>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/56vcoetk/)

Comment: Yours works the same as [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27312990/1185053). I've added clearfix into that now for proper rendering. Your syntax is nicer though so +1.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to think "mobile first"..

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"> div1 </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-md-push-6"> div3 </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-pull-3"> div2 </div>  
  </div>
```

**Demo:** http://bootply.com/zPPaDT4ZIG

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery :

```
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div id="div1" class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">div1</div>
    <div id="div2" class="col-md-6 col-sm-push-12">div2</div>
    <div id ="div3" class="col-md-3 col-sm-pull-6">div3</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).resize(function(){

       if ($(window).width() <= 480) {  

              $( "#div2" ).appendTo('#div3');

       } else
       {
              $( "#div2" ).appendTo('#div1');
       }  

});



</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go about it, which is a bit more simplistic but uses only Bootstrap:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">div1</div>
    <div class="visible-md visible-lg col-md-6">div2</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">div3</div>
</div>
<div class="row visible-xs visible-sm">
    <div class=" col-sm-12">div2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this would cause a lot of duplicated content (and more data for mobiles to download) which could slow down loading times and cause maintenance issues as if you update copy for div 2 you would need to remember to do it in 2 places